# When should I call MessageQueue.EndReceive()?

Tags: .net, windows, windows-services, msmq

I have been looking at example code for a service that processes messages from MSMQ.  In the code, the EndReceive() method is called right away at the beginning of the ReceiveCompletedEventHandler, and then it begins the task of actually processing the message.  Is it just me, or does this totally miss the point of MSMQ reliability?  Shouldn't EndReceive() only be called once a message has been fully handled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`EndReceive` just means that the message was successfully delivered - it doesn't imply anything about whether you were able to do anything worthwhile with it.

It sounds like you're contemplating an asynchronous transactional read from MSMQ, in which you would only finalize the receipt (remove the message from the queue once and for all) upon fully handling your message, whatever that might mean in your context. But asynchronous transactional reads aren't possible - see the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/43h44x53.aspx):

> Do not use the asynchronous call
>   BeginReceive with transactions. If you
>   want to perform a transactional
>   asynchronous operation, call
>   BeginPeek, and put the transaction and
>   the (synchronous) Receive method
>   within the event handler you create
>   for the peek operation.

Comment: Thanks. So, if transactions are required for acknowledgement of the message, then what happens if you don't call EndReceive()?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question: transactions are **not** required for acknowledgement. To acknowledge receipt, you just have to use the synchronous `Receive` method *or* - in an asynchronous scenario - you have to call `EndReceive`.

Comment: Ok, that was my question: If I fail to call EndReceive don't I thereby forgo acknowledgement, and therefore shouldn't I wait until I've successfully processed the message to call it?

Comment: I just realized that I've failed to emphasize the most important thing here: you have to call `EndReceive` (or `Receive`) just to get the `Message` you want. If you want the message to go back onto the queue in the event of an exception during processing (or a power outage, or something similar), you should perform a [transactional receive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc8teys8.aspx).

Comment: Ooohhh! I see...

Message message = messageQueue.EndReceive(asyncResult.AsyncResult);

...you can't access the message without calling it.  Thanks, that cleared it up.